# Jenkins Pipeline: How to print stack trace of hung process on timeout?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my testing, the Pipeline Timeout Step will kill the hung process before it reaches your catch block, so there seems to be no way to run "jstack" (for example) because it is too late:

```
try{ 
  timeout(time: 3, unit: 'SECONDS') {
    sh "some slow/hanging java process"
  }
} catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {
   //check that the cause is org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.TimeoutStepExecution.ExceededTimeout
   // then try to run jstack on all java processes on the machine.
   // but that won't work because the offending process is already gone, 
   // "timeout" killed it...
}
```

To generalize, **how can I debug the process that's taking too long without killing it?**

The only solution I can think of is really ugly, something like this:

```
def ok = false
def alarmTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 50000 //just before timeout
parallel main: {
  timeout(60000) {
    //run java
    ok = true
  } 
}, watcher: {
  waitUntil {
    ok || System.currentTimeMillis() > alarmTime
  }
  if (!ok) {  
    //perform debugging just before timeout fires.
  }
}
```

But this is ugly in code and in output...

**UPDATE:** I opened [JENKINS-54415](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53315) with a proposal to fix this.

Comment: Is this code in your Jenkinsfile or in a shared library?  Could you please provide some more context.

Comment: @AndrewGray this is in an Jenkinsfile, and I believe that it would work the same way in a shared library.

Comment: I you look at how the timeout step kills something it is really ugly. It does feel like something should be done in Jenkins pipeline internally to trace long-running steps and record a callstack that can be obtained when aborting the pipeline with a timeout or any other means. https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-basic-steps-plugin/blob/stable/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/TimeoutStepExecution.java

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the [timeout command](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html) (part of coreutils).

Example:

```
timeout --preserve-status --kill-after=30m --signal=3 20m <command>
```

This will print a thread stack trace dump after 20 minutes, and kill the process after 30 minutes.

I typically wrap it in an additional timeout block in the Jenkinsfile with slightly higher timeout just to catch processes that just won't exit.
Example:

```
timeout(time: 35, unit: 'MINUTES') {
  sh "timeout --preserve-status --kill-after=30m --signal=3 20m sbt test"
}
```

Comment: The code in the question is already using `timeout`. This isn't even an attempt at answering the question.